# If any of this 50 cells = specific cell, then input the column header from that line in my result column

Tags: excel, vba

Each line is a sample
in column K i have the sub-samples  carried out on that sample
in column L to BP I have the different possible results.

90 % of the time all the sub-samples are the same result, so i would like that result to show in column BQ, if there are only one result.

The way to determin if there is only one result is easy, if the number in column one of the columns L to BP is = column P then all of the sub-samples are in this column and the result in BQ is = the header i have in line 5

I could do this with alot of IF statements like thisin each cell in column BQ :

`=if.error(IF(K7*1<1;"";IF(K7=M7;$M$6;HVIS(N7=K7;$N$6;IF(K7=V7;$V$6;IF(K7=X7;$X$6;IF(K7=L7;L6;IF(K7=W7;$W$6;"")))))));"")`

This is the if statement for 6 columns but there are 33, and perhaps more vile come in the future

So i hope there is a better way.

How it looks:

[image: how it looks]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having a bit of a hard time understanding exactly what the problem is, but this may help. Also please remember to accept as answer or +1 !!!

**Formulas:**

```
{=IF(SUM(C3:E3)/SUM(COUNTA(C3:E3)*1)=B3,INDEX(C2:E2,MATCH(FALSE,ISBLANK(C3:E3),0)),"NONE")}

{=IF(SUM(C4:E4)/SUM(COUNTA(C4:E4)*1)=B4,INDEX(C3:E3,MATCH(FALSE,ISBLANK(C4:E4),0)),"NONE")}
```

**Demo:**

[image]